# Design of queues with JMS & QPID

Tags: jms

I am currently assigned the task of writing an application which will use JMS API to communicate using Apache qpid as the JMS provider.

so basically my application will have multiple instances of a server running.Each server will serve a set of unique desks.so each instance will only have data for the desks it is serving.

There will also be multiple instances of clients each configured by desk again.

Now when the client starts up, it will request the data for the desk it is serving to the servers.The request should only go to the server that has that desk data loaded and the response should only go back to the client who requested the data for that desk.

I am thinking of using queues for this.i am not sure if i should create only one request queue which will be used by all the servers or i should create seperate queues for each server.

For response ,I am planning to use temporary queues.

Not that the request from the client to the server is not very often.Say each client may send around 50 requests a day.

can someone please tell me if this is a good design?